# Postmaster add-on - Is it able to handle emailing file attachments?

Tags: postmaster, objective-html

Is the [Postmaster](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster) add-on by Objective HTML able to send file attachments?

Basically I have a channel ([Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/) member) which has a `SafeCracker File` field contained within it. All I want to do is to email the file to an Administrator when a channel entry is updated.

I couldn't find any mention of attachments in the documents for the add-on. Has anyone done this sort of thing before?

Comment: Last I spoke with Justin about this, Postmaster did not support attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments are not currently supported simply because there hasn't really been much of a demand for them. But it has come up more recently. The attachments would work on a per-service basis, so the API needs modified to make that easier. I will put this on the radar for 1.4, which is bringing several additional changes to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin. Have you any idea how big of a job this might be? Do you already have an idea how you might approach this or does it need a bit of thinking about first? Also, any idea when 1.4 is likely to be ready? Sorry for the wall of questions!